# How to extract the href value from links in HTML data based on then element's text?

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping

I have been tasked with the coding of a web crawler that goes through several URLs (around 400, but the list could grow), each with a completely different html structure and extract the links containing certain information. The only thing the program knows beforehand is what are the keywords it should search for, but the html structure and any semantic cues as to where to look for those keywords is unknown.

So far, I have used the request-promise module for Node.js to send a request to the URL where the search for keywords will take place:

```
const htmlResult = await request.get(url);
```

`htmlResult` stores the response as a string, and I can save it both as an .txt or .html if needed.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to instruct the program how to extract a URL based on words that aren't necessarily present in the url string. An example might help clarify:

```
<a href="site/with/no/keywords-just-a-random-string" title="Keywords might be here, but title attribute might be absent"><span class="img"><img data-cfsrc="/thumbpdf/618a8nb4.jpg" alt="" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"><noscript><img src="/thumbpdf/8bfa84.jpg" alt=""></noscript></span>
<h2>KEYWORDS ARE IN THIS TAG, WHICH IN TURN IS INSIDE THE <a> TAG</h2>
<span class="date--type">2 Nov 2021 </span>
<span class="tag">
oher stuff with no keywords in it</span>
</a>
```

As you can see, this  tag has a complex structure. The keywords I need to parse are inside an h2 tag which, in turn, is inside the a tag. But he a tag could also be like this:

```
 <a href="string/with/no-keywords-to-parse">KEYWORDS TO PARSE</a>
```

Here the keywords are simply within the a tag.

My question, thus, is how do I parse htmlResult (either as a string or saved as a .txt/.html file), and, once I get a match, instruct the program to extract the url that is in the bounds of the a tag wherein I go the match of keywords?

As I am using Node.js I open to using any tool available.

Could someone offer some advice on how to tackle this challenge?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you need to match strings. Are you expected to convert the link text to lowercase and add hyphens for comparison? Are you looking for individual words? What are the match criteria? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, isherwood. I don't want to parse the link, because the link might be a random string. I want to extract the link if some words in the text inside the a tag match some words I feed the program with. For example: I want to  search for the words "dog" and "trainer" in all the a tags, and extract the links which are inside an a tag that contains those two words.

Comment: Are you saying that `<h2>` ALWAYS has `dog` and `trainer` in it, or that key words could be in either `<h2>`, `title` or `href`?

Comment: or in no tag or attribute at all, as illustrated in the second example

Comment: If by "the second example" you mean `<a href="string/with/no-keywords-to-parse">KEYWORDS TO PARSE</a>`, the keywords are indeed not in any **attribute** of `<a>` but they ARE present in the text node of `<a>`. So, again, to be specific - if keywords exist, are they **required** to be in  `<h2>` and, optionally, in other elements, or - if they exist - they may be absent from `<h2>` but be present in one or more of the other elements (as in that second example)?

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Jack. To your question: they are not required to be in h2, or any other atribute. They MIGHT be present in h2, or some attribute, or simply in the text node of <a>. My point is, precisely, that I cannot know beforehand where in the html's structure the  keywords will e present, all I can know is that the will be present somewhere within the scope of <a>

Comment: I think I got it now: if the keywords are in `<a>` itself (either in an attribute value or text node or both) OR in any attribute value or text node of any child node of `<a>` (`<h2>` or `<span>` in your html) you want the `<href>` attribute value of that `<a>` , and otherwise not; correct?

Comment: Magnificently said, Jack!! Thanks for the great reformulation. Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this? I am in desperate need of help.

Comment: I believe so; let me chew on it for a while.

Comment: Could you please send me your email info to simongou@gmail.com? I promise I won't overwhelm you with messages, it's just to be able to communicate easier on this particular matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is very quick and dirty, and I'm sure it can be further streamlined, but it should get you at least closer to where you need to be.

This assumes a bunch of `<div>` elements, each containing one of your your `<a>` elements, all in one document (see link below). It uses xpath to locate the data:

```
function xpathEval(xpath, context) {
  return document.evaluate(xpath, context, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
}


desiredHrefs = []

let targets = xpathEval("//div[@class='container']", document);

for (let i = 0; i < targets.snapshotLength; i++) {

  let attribs = xpathEval('.//*/@*', targets.snapshotItem(i)),
    texts = xpathEval('.//*/text()', targets.snapshotItem(i));
    
  for (let k = 0; k < attribs.snapshotLength; k++) {
    attribData = attribs.snapshotItem(k).textContent
    if (attribData.includes("trainer") & attribData.includes("dog")) {
      //either
      //console.log(targets.snapshotItem(i).querySelector('a').getAttribute('href'))
      //ot
      let href = xpathEval('.//a/@href', targets.snapshotItem(i));
      desiredHrefs.push(href.snapshotItem(0).textContent)
    }
  }


  for (let j = 0; j < texts.snapshotLength; j++) {

    data = texts.snapshotItem(j).nodeValue.trim().toLowerCase()

    if (data.includes("trainer") & data.includes("dog")) {
      //either
      //console.log(targets.snapshotItem(i).querySelector('a').getAttribute('href'))
      //or
      let href = xpathEval('.//a/@href', targets.snapshotItem(i));
      desiredHrefs.push(href.snapshotItem(0).textContent)
    }
  }
}
for (let href of [...new Set(desiredHrefs)])
  console.log(href)
```

[You can see it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/us82jrLm/1/).

Comment: Superb, Jack!! One question, though. How could I work around the assumptions of the <div>s with class of container? Let's say the <a>s are wrapped inside and <li> element, or a <div> with no class? Is there a way to target the <a> directly without any attributes?

Comment: @simón It's hard to give a generalized answer without seeing the actual htmls. You can remove the class, or change the element tag. You can also target the `<a>`s directly, although that may not always be a good idea - for example, if they are grouped for some reason, and you cant to keep the group structure, etc. etc....